# Why are port numbers stored as strings?

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, port, boost-asio

**The question is:** Why can't I pass port numbers to DNS resolution functions as 16-bit unsigned ints to prevent `std::string` to `unsigned short` conversions?

**Background:**

I am looking at the [Networking TS](https://chriskohlhoff.github.io/networking-ts-doc/doc/networking_ts/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve.html) and the [boost.asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve.html) implementation of the function `tcp::ip::resolver::resolve`. The function takes as input the web address and the port number of the service you want to connect to and performs DNS name resolution. The signature of this function is

```
results_type resolve(string_view host, string_view service, ...);
```

As an example,

```
boost::asio::io_context serv{};
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver res{serv};

std::string web_address{ "www.google.com" };
std::string port_number{ "80" };

auto result = res.resolve(web_address, port_number);
```

performs DNS lookup for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). Ultimately, in the TCP header, the port number will need to be stored as a 16-bit unsigned int. If the user wants to save on the `std::string` to `unsigned short` conversion, the user could have just written

```
unsigned short port_number{ 80 };
```

However, there is no signature in the Networking TS or the boost.asio library for

```
results_type resolve(string_view host, PortType service, ...);
```

(where `PortType` will be a 16-bit unsigned int). Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a thin wrapper around the POSIX [`getaddrinfo(3)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo), which takes a `const char* service`.

Since a string has to be created to pass to `getadddrinfo()` anyways, there's not actually much benefit to having additional overloads that take `uint16_t` port numbers. Using `resolve(web_address, std::to_string(integer_port_number));` works fine, and the overhead of string construction+formatting is dwarfed by the time it takes to do a DNS lookup.

There could absolutely be overloads that takes a `uint16_t` port. It could do the string formatting to some internal buffer on the stack. The savings would be tiny because of short string optimization, but at least the API user won't have to convert integers.

This seems like a thing to suggest to the Boost.Asio developers and Networking TS people. It has precedent in other networking APIs with Python's [`getaddrinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) taking ports as numbers or numeric strings, converting as necessary.

---

And as an aside, ports are not specified by the internet protocol (layer 3 in the OSI model), but separately by UDP and TCP (on the transport layer, layer 4), and this is meant to be a generic resolver for anything on the IP stack. You can imagine some different transport layer where ports aren't 16 bit integers, but 32 bit integers or file names or something else entirely.

Comment: "Since a string has to be created to pass to ```getaddrinfo()``` anyways..." Ah, this passes the buck. My (published in 2020!) networking textbook still used ```gethostbyname```, which didn't require a port number. The port number was just placed in a ```sockaddr_in```. Perhaps the OP should have asked why ```getaddrinfo``` takes a ```char*``` for port number, and then also why ```gethostbyname``` shouldn't be used (it is "obsolete") and why the ```resolve``` function wouldn't use ```gethostbyname```.

Comment: "the overhead of string construction+formatting is dwarfed by the time it takes to do a DNS lookup." I'm not sure this is the case (*in some circumstances*) if you perform DNS lookup asynchronously, which we can start assuming users will do now that C++ has coroutines.

Comment: Furthermore, ```resolve``` takes a ```std::string_view``` whereas ```getaddrinfo``` takes a ```char*```. This are differentiated by the null character being required for a ```char*```. (I assume this requires a copy of the service_name to be passed as a ```char*```.)

Comment: On some further reading, apparently, to avoid converting to a string, you use nullptr as the service and set the value manually. This can be done with Boost by passing an empty string and setting [`.port(number)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/port.html). But this could be significantly simplified if implemented in the networking library. And yes, the string_view is copied to a `std::string` beforehand, but SSO does kick in for a 6 character string.

Answer (score 1):

Ports can also be referred to by names. If you look as `/windows/system32/drivers/etc/services` (I think) under Windows or `/etc/services` in *nix land, you'll see that port `80` can also be referred to as port `http`. Names are preferred as they are better remembered, you don't need to worry what the underlying port is, and you can change the port number on the fly without having to rebuild your code just by editing the `services` file.

Which means that line can also be referred to as:
`std::string port_number{ "http" };`

Comment: Just a warning in case you can't see my deleted answer which said the same thing. It got downvoted for some reason.

Comment: The question is "why can't I pass the ```unsigned short``` to DNS resolution?" rather than "why can I pass a ```std::string``` to DNS resolution?" I tried to edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @MarkWallace because you would need 2 versions. Why? when only one will do? You could say the same thing about the web address which resolves to an unsigned 32bit number for IPv4 or 128bit for IPv6.

Comment: @Bib that's included in the question. If you pass a ```std::string```, you need to do a ```std::string``` to ```unsigned short``` conversion. Why do this when you don't need to? The same doesn't apply to the web address. You convert the web address to the IP address by doing DNS name resolution, which is what the ```resolver::resolve``` function in the question does.

Comment: It's a helper function. If you don't want it's help, then don't use it. You are free to use any method you wish.

Comment: @bib You realize that as part of the Networking TS, this was going to go in the standard library, correct?

Comment: @bib That's why we have function overloading in c++. `resolve(const std::string &host, const std::string &port) { uint16_t p = lookup_service(port); return resolve(host, p); }` isn't too much to ask.